# How can I make a Vertica IN predicate case insensitive?

Tags: sql, vertica, case-insensitive

I would like to make the `IN` predicate of my Vertica query case insensitive.

```sql
select username from user where username in('Jim');
```

I would like the above query to return entries like:
JIM
Jim
JiM

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to make `in` case insensitive. You could string together a bunch of `ILIKE` [statements](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Predicates/LIKE-predicate.htm), but the better way would be to rewrite your query using the `LOWER` string function, and put all items in the `IN` clause in lowercase.

```sql
SELECT username FROM user WHERE LOWER(username) IN ('jim');
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query example ignores case:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_case CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE test_case(f1 varchar(50));
COPY test_case(f1) FROM STDIN;
JIM
Jim
JiM
TestValue
\.

SELECT * FROM test_case
WHERE f1 ilike 'Jim';
```